# Assignment isn't working using generics in a simple way

Tags: java

I would very apprciate if someone could explain to me why u = bar(u,r) in following code isn't working. I just can't find the right explanation.

```
class R {
}

class U {
}

public class Foo {

    public static <T> T bar(T x, T y) {
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        R r = new R();
        U u = new U();

        u = bar(u,r); // why is this not working?
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to U
```

Comment: Define "isn't working".  What is the error

Comment: Does this code even compile? You have not defined `R` and `U` to be of type `<T>`.

Comment: no it doesn't, I would like to know why

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When figuring out which type to use for the generic type `T`, Java looks at the types of the arguments.

In this case, the arguments `u` and `r` are of different, unrelated types (`U` and `R`).

Their closest common ancestor is therefore `Object`, so the return type will be `Object`, which needs a cast to be able to be assigned to `u`.

Comment: thank you for your explenation, I'll accept it ;-) ... another short one... what if I would extend U by R and try to do this u = r, why will this not even compile?

Comment: If you let `U extends R`, then this code tries to assign an `R` object into a `U` reference, which will let you perform `U` specific actions on an `R`. In other words, a cast is needed again. If you let `R extends U` instead, the code compiles just fine, since a reference can always point to a child object without casting.